# VSTO - How to trace email body from bounce back email?

Tags: vsto, exchange-server

I'm new to develop VSTO. I have a Java schedule job to send email daily by SMTP.

If email is bounce back, my outlook would receive bounce back email.

[image]
Here is the question, since I used java program to send email, there is no copy in "sent items" folder. How can I trace back the original email Body from this bounce back email?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data from headers like `Message-ID`, `To`, `From`, `Subject`, `Recieved` property values for identifying the original item in Outlook.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much. How can I search the original item by Message-ID in VSTO program?